# Trying to style apply a css style on a input boxelement which is generated dynamically in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script which generates input boxes dynamically,

```
    var gridBuilder = function() {
    var html = [];
    for (var index = 1; index <= gridSize * gridSize; index++) 
    {

        html.push("<input id='id" + index + "' class='field' type='text' size='3' maxlength='3' name='name" + index + "'/>");
    }
    return html.join("");
};
```

I am applying the following CSS.

```
.field {  
  padding: 5px;  
  font-size: 15px;  
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;  
  outline: none;  
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottombottom, from(#bcbcbe), to(#ffffff));  
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #bcbcbe,  #ffffff);  
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;  
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;  
  border-radius: 3px;  
  border: 1px solid #717171;  
}
```

My css is linked to the correct class isn't it?  The issue is that none of the CSS defined in .field is showing up on my input.

Comment: At first glance it looks like it should work, what is the issue you are having with this code?

Comment: You should post more information about your problem.  If this issue is with the generated markup, you should post an example of that too

Comment: @Zoidberg The issue is that the CSS is having zero effect on the text boxes. They stay the default style. So i wasn't sure if i was referencing to the class correctly.

Comment: @kishanpatel Using firebug (for firefox) I would inspect the newly created input element and see if your .field class is being recognized at all.  It could be that other styles in the page are overriding it.

Comment: @Zoidberg I checked in firebug and the element is showing up with the class 'field' but the css is not being applied.

Comment: @kishanpatel Firebug will show you all the styles that are applied to it, and will show them crossed out if they have been overridden by another CSS class.  So in this case, is it safe to assume that your styles are not showing up at all?

Comment: @Zoidberg yeah, they aren't showing up at all. Not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as expected for me !

I made you a jsFiddle so you can see if you are doing something different :)

http://jsfiddle.net/neYXk/3/

Maybee you are doing a document.write in a bad place an "overwriting" the core html includeing your css ?

You should start using http://jquery.com/ ! Makes js life so much easier :) !

Answer (score 3):

I've put your javascript and css into a JsFiddle, and the style is being picked up. I put in an arbitrary gridSize because I wasn't sure what numbers would be normal.

Check it out here - http://jsfiddle.net/rTw8r/2/

However, there was a typo on your webkit gradient

it should be

```
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#bcbcbe), to(#ffffff));
```

You had bottombottom instead of bottom

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work in jsfiddle but not when it is merged with the rest of my code. Something must be messing it up there.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your CSS file is used on your page.

Comment: Or the second. While it's a good idea to have CSS at the top, it won't cause styles not to be applied.